# How to Reverse order of values in Set<String>

Tags: java, collections, hashmap, set, reverse

I want to reverse the values in the `Set<String>`

So, I am creating a `Set<String>` of keys from some `HashMap` And printing out the values i.e. keys.

```
Set<String> movies =  movieList.keySet();
for(String movie : movies) {
    output += movie + "\n";
}
```

**I need to reverse the values of the `Set<String>` from last value to first values** Is this possible?

Comment: Elements in a `Set` are **not** ordered... a `LinkedHashSet` on the other hand...

Answer (score 1):

If you want the keys of the `Map` to be ordered, you must use a different `Map` implementation, since the keys of a `HashMap` are not ordered.

You can use a `TreeMap`. You can pass to its constructor a `Comparator` that would determine the ordering of the keys. That would determine the order of the keys in the `Set` returned by `keySet()`.

For example, if you want your movies to be sorted according to reversed lexicographical order:

```
Map<String,Movie> moviesByName = new TreeMap<>((s1,s2)->s2.compareTo (s1));
```

or, as lexicore suggested:

```
Map<String,Movie> moviesByName = new TreeMap<>(Comparator.<String>naturalOrder().reversed());
```

Comment: Is it possible to get an example for clarity please?

Comment: 2 questions. String and Movie are the key/value of the hashmap here? And can you elaborate what (s1,s2)->s2.compareTo (s1) means ?

Comment: @Shaz 1. yes 2. that's a lambda expression (available since Java 8). It's a shorter way to implement the `Comparator<String>` interface.

Comment: Did you try reading the JavaDoc of `java.util.Map`? And are you familiar with Java 8 streams and lambda functions?

Comment: I'd use `Comparator.naturalOrder().reversed()` or `Collections.reverseOrder()`, I think it's more declarative.

Comment: @lexicore that does look better, however `Map<String,String> moviesByName = new TreeMap<>(Comparator.naturalOrder().reversed ());` doesn't pass compilation for me.

Comment: @Eran FTFY: `Map<String,String> moviesByName = new TreeMap<>(Comparator.<String>naturalOrder().reversed());`. Not sure why type inference didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Java8 you can try:

```
List<String> sorted = movieList.keySet().stream()
                .sorted(Collections.reverseOrder())
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Or even better if you want only the output String:

```
String output = movieList.keySet().stream()
                .sorted(Collections.reverseOrder())
                .collect(Collectors.joining("\n"));
```

But if the intent is to just reverse the map.keySet as Andreas suggested ... then

```
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>(movieList.keySet());
Collections.reverse(list);
//list is now in reverse order of the keySet
```

Comment: That would sort the values in reverse of the keys *natural* order, not in reverse of the order in the `keySet`.

Comment: Although you are right, but The question in its original context is ambiguous, because the Set from a Map already doesn't have any guarantee that you know the order in which it was populated, so the Set here is not a pure Set with intention of preserving order, also there is a side question between the lines of getting a concatenated result in String. otherwise only a reverse loop could've solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

[JEP 431: Sequenced Collections](https://openjdk.org/jeps/431) (release 9/19/23) in Java 21 has a `reversed()` method to `SortedSet`. This reversed view of the `SortedSet` can iterate in descending order.

```
SortedSet<String> movies =  movieList.keySet();
for(String movie : movies.reversed()) {
    output += movie + "\n";
}
```

That being said you may want to use a `StringBuilder()` for your output variable.

Answer (score 0):

A key quality of a `Set` is that it not sorted. So you need to use another data structure to achieve this goal. The simplest solution may be a `List`, but then you loose the quality of a `Set` to not contain entires that are equal (entry.equals(otherentry) == true)

If you want to retrieve entries in the order of filling (or reverse) and still want to retain the `Set` quality, you may use a [LinkedHashSet](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashSet.html)

The solution of [Eran](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49963262/2229229) is also possible, but there you need to create a comparator that results in the order of addition to the TreeMap.

Answer (score 0):

```
After getting values stored in a Set, Add all values of Set into a List then apply reverse function of list. Below is an example

import java.util.*;
class Test
{
public static void main(String args[])
{
Set h=new LinkedHashSet();
List h2 = new LinkedList();
h.add("Lovely");
h.add("Professional");
h.add("University");
h2.addAll(h);   
System.out.println(h);
Collections.reverse(h2);
System.out.println(h2);
}
}
```

Comment: If you had formatted code to be readable, I might have up-voted it. But then again, an `ArrayList` created straight from `h` would be better. Besides the question is not about an ordered `LinkedHashSet`, but an unordered `keySet` from a `HashMap `.